# Как научиться решать задачи

Tags: java, c++, pascal

Всем доброго дня! Год назад я начал изучать Pascal, сейчас перешел к программированию с++. Читаю, смотрю курсы, изучаю синтаксис. Но, нет четкого алгоритма решения задачи. Нет вообще  представлений как решать задачу. Вроде бы есть догадки, но это все сводится к не решению. Чита ю множество материалов о различных алгоритмов но нет понятии структуры кода((. Посоветуйте, как можно научиться решать задачи. HELP

Comment: а что именно вы подразумеваете под задачами?

Comment: Решать задачи язык программирования не учит, он является инструментом решения задач. Для разных задач могут использоваться разные языки и методики решения. ООП или функциональное и т.д.

Структура кода так же выбирается разработчиком (программистом); то, как будет выглядеть проект, его внутренности, зависит от задачи, сроков ее решения и инструментов которые будут использоваться.

В учебных заведениях обычно начинают с выработки у учащихся понимания принципа работы компьютера, программы. Начинается все с блок-схем и решения примитивных задач (проверок на да\нет, уравнений a=b+c ...).

Comment: Задача 1. Проверить, начинается ли каждый из членов последовательности с цифры, на которую оканчивается предыдущий
Задача 2. Проверить, является ли последовательность пилообразной?
таких вот типов задач имею ввиду

Comment: @Rang спасибо за ответ. думаю, опыт еще совсем мал у меня. Соображалки не хватает))

Answer (score 5):

Для начала, можно преставить как бы ты сам решал эту задачу без компьютера с одними данными, потом с другими, понять свой алгоритм действий, и уже потом написать программу, которая выполняла твой алгоритм действий.

> Задача 1. Проверить, начинается ли каждый из членов последовательности с цифры, на которую оканчивается предыдущий

Есть последовательность: 123 221 112

Как бы я это делал без компьютера:

1. Всю последовательность я бы прочитать и запомнить не смог бы, поэтому буду читать по одному числу. Прочитаю первое число 123, т.е. "проверяемое число 1" = 123
2. Прочитаю следующее число 221, т.е. "проверяемое число 2" = 221
3. Смотрю на два числа, у "проверяемое число 1" смотрю последний символ и "проверяемое число 2" смотрю первый символ / 3 не равно 2.
4. Дальше можем считать следующее число 112. "проверяемое число 1" теперь будет равно 221, а "проверяемое число 2" равно 112. И переходим на 2-ой шаг.

Надо научиться составлять алгоритмы, строить блок схемы или любые другие аналоги.

Думаю у тебя все получиться! :)

Answer (score 2):

Есть 3 кита на которых держится алгоритмизация в программировании:

1. *Ветвление*: применяется если необходимо в зависимости от каких то условий применить другой участок кода
2. *Цикл*: применяется если надо применить однотипное действие несколько раз
3. *Функция/процедура*: применяется если один и тот же код встречается несколько раз

**Пример:** вычисляем сумму квадратов заданной последовательности неотрицательных чисел

1. Пускаем цикл по последовательности чисел (*цикл*)
2. Проверяем число на неотрицательности, если число больше нуля возводим в квадрат, если меньше нуля пропускаем (*ветвление*)
3. Поскольку возведение в степень часто повторяющаяся операция - делаем из нее *процедуру/функцию* (можно использовать библиотечную функцию возведения в степень).